# FatalErrorException in EventController.php line 22: Class 'App\Event' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am in stuck with defining model in controller . I have tried several solutions in stackoverflow but nothing helps.

My **Route**

```
Route::resource('/events' , 'EventController');
```

My model: **Event.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';

    protected $hidden = ['remember_token'];

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    protected $fillable = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required|min:5',
        'price' => 'required|number'
      );
}
```

In my **Controller** :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Event;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use View;

use Validator;

use Redirect;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    //Show lists of the events
    public function index()
    {
        $events = \App\Event::all();

        return view('admins.events.index' , compact($events));
    }
}
```

I think the problem is like I am missing something in my model. Can you please point out the error ?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this . Also did composer dump-autoload. Doesn't help

Comment: you mean `\App\Models\Event::all()`

Comment: someone commented and then deleted so you see the comment. I have just tried what you wrote but does not seem to work.

Comment: what's the message error?

Comment: FatalErrorException in EventController.php line 22:
Class 'App\Models\Event' not found

Comment: update your autoloader with `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: At least 20 times I have done that. Isn't working :(

Comment: you can read about psr here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. Put Event.php in `app/Models/` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

`use App\Models\Event`

instead of

```
use App\Event
```

in your controller.

and in your index method refer to Event using only `Event` and not the fully qualified name i.e `\App\Event`.

Add this to your composer.json file.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap":[
       "app/"
    ]
}
```

then run `composer dump`.

and load your view like this, you are using compact in the wrong way.

```
return view('admins.events.index' , compact('events'));
```

That should do it.

Comment: FatalErrorException in EventController.php line 22:
Class 'App\Models\Event' not found

Comment: then your models directory needs to be autoloaded in the composer.

Comment: I did composer dump-autoload

Comment: could not scan for classes inside "app/models/" which does not appear to be a file or folder

Comment: where does the file Event.php exists in your directory structure?

Comment: app/Event.php here

Comment: okay then use `app/` in the class map instead of `app/models`

Comment: I have moved Event.php from app/ to app/Models . I checked the variable by print_r and it returns the data. But when I send it to the view file it says undefined variable events.

Answer (score 1):

You `Event` is in `App\Models` so you need to make `use` look like this:

```
use App\Models\Event;
```

otherwise you reference class that does not exists, hence the error you facing.

Also you when you use `use`, you do this basically to avoid need to type full namespace, so this (I am using correct namespace, not one from your question):

```
$events = \App\Models\Event::all();
```

can be shortened to just

```
$events = Event::all();
```

Also note that even if you correct `use` you **must** either correct the namespace in the code above (because it is invalid and `use` is not going to fix that for you) or replace the invocation with short version as in above example.

Finally `composer dumpautoload` prior testing may not hurt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not solve the problem. Now it says : FatalErrorException in EventController.php line 22:
Class 'App\Models\Event' not found

Comment: It was not. Now it is in app/Models . Now it shows another problem which is : ErrorException in 7feaca4ff5192398d8179909026f6fc027df2533.php line 6:
Undefined variable: events (View: C:\wamp\www\blog\resources\views\admins\events\index.blade.php)

Comment: This is related to your compiled view. Remove all cached views and run your app again. If this show up again. check your template file for the same bad reference to Events or how you assign `$events` for the template.

Comment: Actually I never used my Model. I could solve it by following the answer above. Thanks